# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named money-transfer

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jpa

OMG, I have searched and looked through related answers here but nothing seem to resolve my issue which is that i am getting the error whenever i run my web app using intelliJ IDE

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named money-transfer
```

which is thrown by the line below

```
     EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("money-transfer");
```

my persistence.xml is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="money-transfer" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test" />

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My project structure is below
[image: IntelliJ project structure]

I am using the below hibernate dependency in my pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

so i found a way around this, apparently, the META-INF folder should be a child of the resources folder, hope this helps folks with the same issue.